# Making curl-like request with Python requests?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I need to make a python request, like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
https://api.getnomi.com/v2/reports/conversion?account=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\&store=XXXXXXXXXX\&date_from=1329238082\&date_to=1360860473
```

I tried this:

`import requests as r`

```
auth_code = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
account_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
store_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

test_url = "https://api.getnomi.com/v2/reports/conversion?"


header = {"Authorization": auth_code}
payload = {"account": account_id, "store": store_id,
           "date_from": 1398272878, "date_to": 1398359278}

data = r.get(test_url, params=payload, headers=header)
```

and I keep getting this response `<Response [404]>`

Any idea why?

Comment: Does removing the `?` from your URL help? It's normally the GET url parameters delimiter.

Comment: Otherwise, your request looks correct to me.

Comment: nope, unfortunately that does not change anything.

Comment: How is the `auth_code` value produced? Is it based on the request URL perhaps (like HMAC signature)? In that case, order matters.

Comment: The authcode is a key given to me by the company.

Comment: What happens if you *don't* use `params` but just use the full URL with query parameters as sent by curl? So `test_url = "https://api.getnomi.com/v2/reports/conversion?account=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&store=XXXXXXXXXX&date_from=1329238082&date_to=1360860473"` If this works, order matters and I can show you how to ensure that.

Comment: I also note that the `date_from` and `date_to` values differ between your curl attempt and the `requests.get()` call; are you certain those parameters cannot be the cause?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The i changed the dates in the python request because the curl attempt is from the companies documentation.  I changed the dates to a time when the software was activated for me.  As for using `test_url` without `params`, this also did not work...still receiving the 404 error.

Comment: Then you'll have to ask the API vendor for support I am afraid. This is a straightforward GET request and the server doesn't seem to behave for you.

Comment: Yes, it seems that way.  Oh well, thanks for you help!

Comment: I would make sure that data I am sending is correct by checking  request.headers() and see if provider gives different response based on user agent